# R Equivalents of S plus functions

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to get predictions from a fitted linear regression model in R using the S plus functions predict and pointwise. I was just wondering if anyone knew the R equivalents of these. I know there is `predict` in R but the `se.fit = TRUE` argument is not available in R. My codes are given below:

Using mtcars as sample data:

```
# S plus codes
model.lm <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
newData <- data.frame(disp=300)
predict.disp <- predict(model.lm, newData, se.fit = TRUE)
pointwise(predict.disp, 0.99)
```

I've tried running the code below in R but it doesn't seem to give me the same thing as the S plus output obtained in the above code:

```
predict(model.lm, newData, interval = "prediction", level = 0.99)
```

Has anyone else come across this problem in R?

Edit:

Here's what pointwise does in S plus:

```
function(results.predict, coverage = 0.99)
{
fit <- results.predict$fit
limits <- qt(1 - (1 - coverage)/2, results.predict$df)*results.predict$se.fit
list(upper = fit + limits, fit = fit, lower = fit - limits)
}
```

Thanks for all your answers. I guess another idea is to use the above code in R.

Comment: Well, `predict` should be the same. Why not tell use what `pointwise` does?

Comment: “the `se.fit = TRUE` argument is not available in R.” — yes, it is!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out-you're right, se.fit is available in R. I'll tell you what pointwise does in a minute.

Comment: http://www.uni-muenster.de/ZIV.BennoSueselbeck/s-html/helpfiles/pointwise.html ; I think you're going to have to show us the results you got in S-PLUS in order for us to help (it might not hurt to print `model.lm` too), because very few of us have access to S-PLUS ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mismatch is due to computing prediction rather than confidence intervals.

```
predict(model.lm, newData, interval="confidence", level=0.99)
       fit      lwr      upr
1 17.23532 15.41756 19.05308
```

The results are identical (up to differences in vector vs. list, order, and names of lower and upper bounds) to using the `pointwise` function provided above:

```
pointwise(predict.disp,0.99)
$upper
       1 
19.05308 

$fit
       1 
17.23532 

$lower
       1 
15.41756
```

Answer (score 4):

After looking at a help page for pointwise I think this does it:

```
est <- predict(lm(y ~ x), new, se.fit = TRUE)
matplot(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.5), est$fit + cbind( est$se.fit*-1.96, 0, est$se.fit*1.96))
```

[image]